# Importing custom csv from my custom module magento

Tags: magento, csv, import

I am new to magento and I am trying to import a csv file from my custom module. I will try to explain it more. I have created a module to enter a region information(i.e region name, cost etc..), it works perfectly, I can add new region.Now i'm trying to add a "import" button from wihch i can import a csv file that contain the information about multiple region which is to be saved in my region table in magento's database.FYI I am using flat table.

Till now I am able to bring a button on the Grid view aside "Add New" while clicking, it redirects to a import function. after this I couldn't figure out what to do, I think the choose file menu should appear to choose my csv but i couldn't get to it.Can anyone help please.Any help would be appriciable.

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a resource model for your custom entity (otherwise it won't work).
The resource model should be placed in `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Resource/[Entity].php`.
Create this method inside that resource model

```
public function saveImportData(array $data){
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $columns = array('region_name', 'cost'); //add here all your column names except the autoincrement column.
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($this->getMainTable(), $data, $columns);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Now in the action where you upload your file, parse that file and create an array with the rows to be inserted.

Your array should look like this:

```
$toImport = array(
    array('region_name' => 'Region 1', 'cost'=>'12.99', ...rest of the fields here), 
    array('region_name' => 'Region 2', 'cost'=>'17.99', ...rest of the fields here), 
    ....
)
```

Now you just need to call in the controller

```
Mage::getResourceModel('[module]/[entity]')->saveImportData($toImport);
```